# How to replace the first blank space, within a string, with a different character?

Tags: php

I have a text (.txt) file that contains text like this:

```
5 General
-10 Time Limits
-20 Scheduled Maintenance Checks
-30 Reserved 
-40 Reserved
-50 Unscheduled Maintenance checks

6 DIMENSIONS and AREAS

7 LIFTING and SHORING
-00 General
-10 Jacking
-20 Shoring

8 LEVELING and WEIGHING
-00 General
-10 Weighing and Balancing
-20 Leveling

9 TOWING and TAXIING
-00 General
-10 Towing
-20 Taxiing
```

I want to replace the first space in each line with a comma (I'm trying to convert a txt file to a csv to prepare it for importing into a db). I started down the track of using `strpos()` function, but couldn't get my head around what to do next.

Bonus task: I also want a semi colon at the end of each line.

**EDIT :** Added actual data instead of sample data.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what a string would look like before, then after you replace the spaces?

Comment: @che-azeh That would replace all of the spaces, not just the first one.

Comment: Are you looking for only PHP solution? It is super easy to fix this using unix shell commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with limit will work:

```
$str = '5 Here is some text.';

echo preg_replace('/ /', ',', $str, 1); 

//  OUTPUT:
//  5,Here is some text.
```

With loop:

```
<?php

$str = array('5 Here is some text.', '5 Here is some text.','-10 Here is some text.','-20 Here is some text.','-30 Here is some text');
foreach ($str as $a) {
echo preg_replace('/ /', ',', $a, 1)."<br>";
}

// OUTPUT:
// 5,Here is some text.
// -10,Here is some text.
// -20,Here is some text.
// -30,Here is some text.
```

EDIT FOR YOUR NEW EDIT:

```
$str = "5 General
-10 Time Limits
-20 Scheduled Maintenance Checks
-30 Reserved 
-40 Reserved
-50 Unscheduled Maintenance checks

6 DIMENSIONS and AREAS

7 LIFTING and SHORING
-00 General
-10 Jacking
-20 Shoring

8 LEVELING and WEIGHING
-00 General
-10 Weighing and Balancing
-20 Leveling

9 TOWING and TAXIING
-00 General
-10 Towing
-20 Taxiing";

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

foreach ($array as $a) {

echo preg_replace('/ /', ',', $a, 1)."<br>";
}

// OUTPUT:

/*
5,General
-10,Time Limits
-20,Scheduled Maintenance Checks
-30,Reserved
-40,Reserved
-50,Unscheduled Maintenance checks

6,DIMENSIONS and AREAS

7,LIFTING and SHORING
-00,General
-10,Jacking
-20,Shoring

8,LEVELING and WEIGHING
-00,General
-10,Weighing and Balancing
-20,Leveling

9,TOWING and TAXIING
-00,General
-10,Towing
-20,Taxiing
*/
```

Comment: Tis does not replace the word here.

Comment: I like this one, but with all of my text in the same .txt file, this would result in "-,10 Here is some text." for the other lines, right?

Comment: @AndrewFox no, why? Is there a space between the - and the 10?

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific. I had previously said "text something like this:" and didn't emphasis the "something" enough.

Comment: my string is not an array, the txt file is as shown.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Every line of your text file is ended by EOL and php will read it line by line, so just add the preg replace in the loop

Comment: BTW: I only read the string and explode it by the end of line (PHP_EOL) to an array, this will work for you too

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_pos()` and `str_replace()`:

```
$csvData = array();
foreach (file("input.txt") as $line) {
    $spacePos = str_pos($line, ' ');
    $csvData[] = substr($line, 0, $spacePos) . ',' . substr($line, $spacePos + 1);
}
```

Or you can go to the more advanced `preg_replace()` to search and replace a pattern:

```
$csvData = array();
foreach (file("input.txt") as $line) {
    $csvData[] = preg_replace('/^([^ ]+) /', '\1,',  $line);
}
```